# Can't ssh without password to some machines, on a shared filesystem on a cluster, while it is successful on other machines

Tags: ssh, password, authentication

I am running on a cluster, where my home directory is shared to all machines. Some of the machines are RHEL and the others are Ubuntu.

When I login without password from RHEL->RHEL or UBUNTU->RHEL it is successful. However, when I try anything->UBUNTU, it fails and I need to manually type the password.

**EDIT1: It fails only when trying to connect to some Ubuntu machines. Connecting to other Ubuntu machines is successful.**

I made sure the setting of `~` and `~/.ssh` to `chmod 700` and `authorized_keys` to `chmod 600`, but it didn't help.

**EDIT2: I added below the output of  `namei -lx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`**

**EDIT3: I added below the output of ssh in debug mode on a machine I have sudo for. Surprisingly (although above), it says `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.**

I deleted and recreated the ssh keys, and it was also with no success (ssh to non-sudo machines still works, ssh to with-sudo doesn't). 
The commands I used were:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub ubuntu_machine_name
```

Here is the output when doing `ssh -vv host`

```
[my_user@ctx01 .ssh]$ ssh -vv 10.20.30.40
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options or *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.20.30.40 [10.20.30.40] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 130/256
debug2: bits set: 480/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.20.30.40' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 519/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-my_userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f412fd53880)
debug2: key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
my_user@10.20.30.40's password:
```

Here is the output of `namei -lx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
f: /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
Drwxr-xr-x root   root    /
drwxr-xr-x root   root    home
Drwxr-xr-x nobody nogroup lab
drwx------ nobody nogroup my_user
drwx------ nobody nogroup .ssh
-rw------- nobody nogroup authorized_keys
```

Here is the output of ssh in debug mode:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user my_user service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 2117/505 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 2117/505 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/lab/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/lab/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for my_user from 10.20.30.40 port 48718 ssh2: RSA 90:42:ea:e3:79:b2:27:67:49:1b:17:0b:db:b6:ad:eb
```

Comment: How is the home directory shared? NFS? Please add the output of `namei -lx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Hi @muru, I think it is NFS (I am not the admin). I added the output of `namei -lx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to the question

Comment: Check with your admin how your home directory is mounted. It's possible it's mounted [at login using Kerberos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto#NFSv4_with_Kerberos), meaning the SSH daemon can't access your home directory until you login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to the fact that the NFS was not configured correctly on the Ubuntu machines. When I did `ls -l` the file owner and group were `nobody nogroup`. Once I fixed the NFS configuration, everything went well.